# Add TLS to Traefik 2 router end with unavailable service

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik, lets-encrypt

I have installed Traefik 2.8 on my server with Docker and I try to make the `whoami` docker image available through https with letsencrypt and acme challenge.
I can access whoami service without https configuration but when I add tls to the router labels, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my config:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  reverseproxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:v2.8
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - /srv/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    - /srv/acme.json:/acme.json
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverseproxy.rule=Host(`reverseproxy.domain.dev`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverseproxy.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverseproxy.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_USER}:${TRAEFIK_PASSWORD}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.headerField=X-WebAuth-User"
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.domain.dev`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certResolver=le"
```

*traefik.toml*

```
[providers.docker]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.websecure]
  address = ":443"
[api]
  dashboard = true
[certificatesResolvers.le.acme]
  email = "mail@domain.dev"
  storage = "acme.json"
  caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
  keyType = "EC384"
[certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "web"
```

When I comment the 2 tls lines on whoami service labels, I can access http://whoami.domain.dev

but if I uncomment those 2 lines, I have those results:

https://whoami.domain.dev/ give me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

and

http://whoami.domain.dev/ give me the 404 error from traefik.

When I look inside the acme.json file, I can see that the certificate have been created for whoami.domain.dev

I am pretty sure it's not a big matter but I can't figure it out =)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to expose the 443 port on the docker-compose.yml of traefik :

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "8080:8080"
  - "443:443" <---
```

And now I can access https://whoami.domain.dev/ and http://whoami.domain.dev